# Instant Run doesn't work with proguard

Tags: android, proguard

I am researching the "instant run" feature in Android Studio. But it looks like it doesn't work with proguard. Is there anybody know why and how to get them work together?

My environment: Android Studio 2.0 Beta 4

My top level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

The build.gradle for module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

I can see some following "instatn run" tasks in gradle console with the above setting. And there is a yellow thunderbolt appear with the run button.

```
:TestIR:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug
:TestIR:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug
:TestIR:transformClasses_enhancedWithInstant+reloadDexForDebug
:TestIR:generateDebugInstantRunAppInfo
:TestIR:transformClassesWithInstantRunSlicerForDebug
Dexing C:\git\android\TestIR\build\intermediates\transforms\instantRunSlicer\debug\folders\1\5\slice_1 took 328
Dexing C:\git\android\TestIR\build\intermediates\transforms\instantRunSlicer\debug\folders\1\5\slice_0 took 340
Dexing C:\git\android\TestIR\build\intermediates\transforms\instantRunSlicer\debug\folders\1\5\slice_2 took 331
Dexing C:\git\android\TestIR\build\intermediates\transforms\instantRunSlicer\debug\folders\1\5\slice_5 took 321
Dexing C:\git\android\TestIR\build\intermediates\transforms\instantRunSlicer\debug\folders\1\5\slice_3 took 456
```

But if I set "minifyEnabled" to true, there is no "instant run" task in Gradle console any more, either the yellow thunderbolt button.

Is there anyway to get them work together?

Comment: Why is proguard running at all with a run function? It should only run for a signed application, right?

Comment: One thing that I was thinking of doing is making a developer build type that has `minifyEnabled false` and only test on newer devices with that while developing and then switching to debug one

Comment: @TaylorCourtney when your minsdk is low enough, you need to run proguard simply to meet the dex limit. You don't need to use it for obfuscation unless it is in production but you need to trim extra methods to test on older devices

Comment: I see.... Maybe make it so pro guard only runs on the lower devices and not newer ones? Or is that what you are already doing?

Comment: @TaylorCourtney, as Mike said, the reason I set the "minifyEnabled" to true is to trim extra methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html) official Android developer page, Android Studio disables ProGuard when using Instant Run.[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to **'run/debug configurations'** remove your android application configuration

2.**Recreate** an android application configuration

3.Go to **miscellaneous** tab, uncheck '**force stop running application before launching activity**'

Comment: With `minifyEnabled true` you don't even see the run button with the lightning bolt for instant run. The only way I was able to have it actually show up is to turn off proguard, unless there are more steps to this that are missing